# Zenbook UX31A USB3 not recognised and not working

Tags: usb, kernel, hardware, detect, xhci-hcd

I have a Zenbook UX31A and Ubuntu 12.10 upgraded to /latest/ kernel 3.8.6-030806-generic. My USB3 controller is not recongnized and I am stuck with USB 2.0 speeds. Listing of dmesg has no mention of usb followed by number 3 or xhci. Threre are no modules modules containing xhci in mane.

I'll get back with results from Win8, when I reboot next time.

Please help to diagnose.

```
10:09:48 ~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0153 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)

10:09:58 ~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:7908 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0b95:7e2b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b368 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.
```

Comment: My kernel parameters are: quiet acpi_osi= splash rootfstype=ext4 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 nmi_watchdog=0 $vt_handoff

Answer (score 0):

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#Not_yet_solved It's a bug in the driver that hasn't been fixed yet (?) or the update hasn't come through.